# NSubstitute and Covariance Support?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, covariance, nsubstitute

I'm trying to test some TPL dataflow code and run into what looks like a covariance issue with NSubstitue param matching. It is asserting:

```
Expected to receive exactly 1 call matching:
  Subscribe("987123", any ITargetBlock`1) 
Actually received 1 matching call:
  Subscribe("987123", ActionBlock<ChainLinkFakeData>)
```

From a matcher of:

```
childFakeSubscriptionSource
    .Received(1)
    .Subscribe(
        Arg.Is<string>("987123"),
        Arg.Any<ITargetBlock<ChainLinkFakeData>>());
```

So the stumbling block appears to be that it isn't covariant matching ITargetBlock to the implementing class ActionBlock.

Is there a way to do this without explicitly matching to ActionBlock, or is it just a current limitation of NSubstitute?

edit: for everyones convenience, this is the class signature of ActionBlock. I think this is enough to see the covariance issue without pulling in a tonne of interfaces etc.

```
public sealed class ActionBlock<TInput> : ITargetBlock<TInput>, IDataflowBlock
```

The nub of the issue is that through covariance, `ITargetBlock<T>` should match an `ActionBlock<T>`. The arg matchers `Arg.Any<ITargetBlock<ChainLinkFakeData>>()` in NSubstitute don't seem to?

The easy work around is `Arg.Any<ActionBlock<ChainLinkFakeData>>()` but that requires knowledge of the subject under tests implementation.

In terms of simpler example, I haven't tested this, but I expect that there would be similar probs with `IEnumerable<T>` not matching `List<T>`.

Comment: Can you show an example of the interface, do you have a simple test that shows the behavior?

Comment: @Danh - This looks like a threading issue to me. It expected 1 call and received 1 matching call -- that should mean the expectation matched correctly. There is an [unreleased fix in the master branch](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/blob/master/CHANGELOG.txt#L6).

Comment: @DT Are you sure its not matching? It looked more like a match problem from the error message. I will put in a wait and see if that makes any odds. FWIW if I tell it to match on ActionBlock<T> it works fine, which speaks against threading too I think?

Comment: @DT - I came back to this and realised that my fix of making it an ActionBlock<T> didn't always work, so I went back to ITargetBlock<T> with a Sleep(1000) above it and it now passes. So thanks you answered it. If you put your response in a proper answer I can credit you the points by marking correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in NSubstitute, which should be fixed as of v1.4.0. (See [original issue](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/64))